# Project target does not exist com Ionic (android)

Tags: android, angular, ionic, apache-cordova

Boa tarde.

Estou criando um novo aplicativo Ionic (Android).

Quando vou rodar o código: `ionic cordova prepare android --prod` ou `ionic cordova build android` ele acaba gerando erro de target e não sei nem por reza como arrumar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-PT! Para que outros usuários possam te ajudar com mais facilidade, recomendo que você leia [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para ter umas dicas de como fazer uma boa pergunta.  Sugiro, também, que você forneça mais detalhes do seu código, dizendo o que ele faz, o trecho em que está, etc.

Comment: Faça `ionic cordova platform add android` Refência: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-platform

Answer (score 0):

Qual versão está usando?
Existe um bug reportado, mas já corrigido em uma posterior versão

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```

execute a atualização e tente novamente caso esteja abaixo da v6.19.0

Comment: Eu rodei o código seu para atualizar, eu estava na 6.18.1.
Agora esta na v6.19 porém não deu feito nenheum criei o projeto... ao dar o prepare android ele da o mesmo erro ...

Comment: consegue postar suas dependências? seu cordova e ionic cli, quais versões estão instaladas? tem android e java sdk instalados?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar os builders:

```
ng add @ionic/cordova-builders
```